# Should build-key-server be used with OpenVPN?

Tags: linux, centos, vpn, openvpn

When I read these howto's

http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Openvpn

http://library.linode.com/networking/openvpn/centos-5

on setting up an OpenVPN server, I see that only the last of the two have the step

```
. /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/2.0/build-key-server server
```

Should that step also have been in the Fedora howto, or is it not required?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

build-key-server is just a different type of key to use for OpenVPN. You could use any of the following and be ok

```
build-key mycert (no password protection)
build-key-pass mycert (with password protection)
build-key-pkcs12 mycert (PKCS #12 format)
build-key-server mycert (with nsCertType=server)
```

Comment: Ok, so `./build-inter mycert` that Fedora have in their howto could be added your you list and therefore substitutes `build-key-server`?

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple options for building your keys with easy-rsa. Using the "build-key-server" builds the certificate as a server-only certificate (nsCertType=server) and requires the "ns-cert-type server" to be placed in your OpenVPN configuration file.

For the most comprehensive set of instructions, always refer to the official OpenVPN documentation:

http://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/miscellaneous/77-rsa-key-management.html

Comment: Excellent. I can see that it is default in the client.conf, so I'll use it =) Thanks for pointing that out.